# Internal error occured due to hg in eclipse

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I get the following errors whenever I start a new project in eclipse.

One thing to observe is the strange path at the last, which i dont know why, comes always in the error message.

ps: the greyed out area is my username.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running Windows 7. Check the security settings on the folders you are working with and make sure that your user has the appropriate permissions on them.